# Delete Query with Inner Join not working

Tags: sql

Having a problem with a simple query:

```
DELETE FROM t_meter_value mv
 INNER JOIN t_channel c ON mv.t_channel_id = c.id
      WHERE (c.t_device_device_address = 16777216 OR 
             c.t_device_device_address = 33619968)
        AND c.t_channelspec_channel_address NOT IN
            (256, 257, 259, 263, 261, 326, 271, 281, 273, 32778);
```

I get a syntax error at inner, I am not sure why. When I use the select variant it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Instead, try:

```
delete mv from t_meter_value mv
inner join t_channel c on mv.t_channel_id = c.id
where (
    c.t_device_device_address = 16777216 or 
    c.t_device_device_address = 33619968
  ) and 
  c.t_channelspec_channel_address not in (
    256, 257, 259, 263, 261, 326, 271, 281, 273, 32778
  );
```

Notice that the alias `mv` was added between the `delete` and the `from`.

This indicates which table should have records removed... you'd also have the option of removing records from your other table by using `delete c from`.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks Martin!  I felt the need to change my picture to something that a hat would fit on...