# Delete with inner join is not working

Tags: mysql, sql

I am deleting games corresponding to a game id from multiple tables.

Here is the query that I am using

```
$sql = DELETE `tb_games`, `tb_game_over`, `tb_game_round_record` FROM `tb_games`";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN `tb_game_over` ON `tb_games`.`game_id` = `tb_game_over`.`game_id`";
$sql .= " INNER JOIN `tb_game_round_record` ON `tb_games`.`game_id` = `tb_game_round_record`.`game_id`";
$sql .= " WHERE `tb_games`.`game_id` = ?";
```

This query is working if game_id is in all the three tables but its not working if game id is only in tb_games table. How can I remove this problem ? Or Do I need to write three different queries to delete from all the three tables ?

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978452/delete-query-with-inner-join-not-working?rq=1

Comment: i think use left join

Comment: yes left join will do the job

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the need to do this in DML by making the game_id columns in tb_game_over and tb_game_round_record foreign keys which point to tb_games.game_id and include the 'on delete cascade ' clause. Then your delete statement will look just like this:

```
delete from tb_games where game_id=?
```

Answer (score 0):

simply you can do like

```
DELETE FROM tb_games WHERE game_id IN (
SELECT game_id FROM tb_game_over
UNION ALL
SELECT game_id FROM tb_game_round_record
);
```